R gt package: How to perform line breaking respecting indentation
When a a string does not fit in a gt table cell (due to cell width) it will break to the 2nd line. However when indentation is used on the cell content then the 2nd line is not indented. Is there a way to correct?
Example:
library(gt)
dat <- data.frame(text = "Some long text I would like to indent")

dat %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "text") %>%
  tab_header(title = "my title") %>% 
  tab_stub_indent(rows = everything(),
                  indent = 5) %>%
  cols_width(text ~ px(200))



Instead of using tab_stub_indent could try using tab_style with padding-left? Something like: tab_style(style = "padding-left:40px", locations = cells_stub())?
